# Fetch values from XML object

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm trying to fetch the values of XML object using java.

**my XML source**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <qde:invokeResponse xmlns:qde="http://qde.service.los">
          <qde:return>
               <ns1:data xmlns:ns1="http://to.service.los/xsd">
                    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                           <Application>
                                <RefNumber>100</RefNumber>
                                <Number>100</Number>
                                <StatusCode>142</StatusCode>

                            </Application>]]></ns1:data>
                 <ns1:errorCode xmlns:ns1="http://to.service.los/xsd">WCP_QUERY_WS_06</ns1:errorCode>
        <ns1:errorMessage xmlns:ns1="http://to.service.los/xsd">Interface Error Occured, Application moved to Error Technical Queue.</ns1:errorMessage>
     </qde:return>
      </qde:invokeResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to fetch Application object.

**my code**

```
def rootnode = new XmlParser().parseText(responseXml);
def rtn = rootnode.'soapenv:Body'.'qde:invokeResponse'.'qde:return'.'ns1:data';

LOG.info("Return value iss:"+rtn);
```

This is printing the following

```
 [{http://to.service.los/xsd}data[attributes={};  
     value=
         [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Application>
         <LeadRef>100</LeadRef>
    <Number>101</Number>
    <StatusCode>142</StatusCode>    </Application>]]]
```

I'm just trying to fetch LeadRef, Number & StatusCode

Comment: your XML Source and the output posted both looks different. Please make sure the output and source xml has identical data? So, that we can provide some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `text()` method:

```
def rtn = rootnode.'soapenv:Body'.'qde:invokeResponse'.'qde:return'.'ns1:data'.text();
LOG.info("Return value iss:"+rtn);
```

This prints the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                       <Application>
                            <RefNumber>100</RefNumber>
                            <Number>100</Number>
                            <StatusCode>142</StatusCode>

                        </Application>
```

Now you can process this XML again:

```
def xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">\n' +
    '   <soapenv:Body>\n' +
    '      <qde:invokeResponse xmlns:qde="http://qde.service.los">\n' +
    '          <qde:return>\n' +
    '               <ns1:data xmlns:ns1="http://to.service.los/xsd">\n' +
    '                    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
    '                           <Application>\n' +
    '                                <RefNumber>100</RefNumber>\n' +
    '                                <Number>100</Number>\n' +
    '                                <StatusCode>142</StatusCode>\n' +
    '\n' +
    '                            </Application>]]></ns1:data>\n' +
    '                 <ns1:errorCode xmlns:ns1="http://to.service.los/xsd">WCP_QUERY_WS_06</ns1:errorCode>\n' +
    '        <ns1:errorMessage xmlns:ns1="http://to.service.los/xsd">Interface Error Occured, Application moved to Error Technical Queue.</ns1:errorMessage>\n' +
    '     </qde:return>\n' +
    '      </qde:invokeResponse>\n' +
    '   </soapenv:Body>\n' +
    '</soapenv:Envelope>'
def rootnode = new XmlParser().parseText(xml);
def rtn = rootnode.'soapenv:Body'.'qde:invokeResponse'.'qde:return'.'ns1:data';
def application = new XmlParser().parseText(rtn.text())
println application.'RefNumber'.text()
```

Result:

```
100
```

See http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html for more info.

Comment: You can again use an XmlParser for that. I will update the answer.

Comment: Throwing error in def application = new XmlParser().parseText(rtn.text())

Comment: Did you remove the .text() from the end of "def rtn = rootnode.'soapenv:Body'.'qde:invokeResponse'.'qde:return'.'ns1:data';" ?

Comment: Oops! yeah. I haven't removed that earlier. Thanks bro.. Its working. Super cool